# NotSerializableException while getting CLOB data from ORACLE using JDBC

Tags: java, oracle, jdbc

When I try to get CLOB data from ORACLE using JDBC, exception occurs:

> Caused by: java.io.NotSerializableException: oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection

Have you any idea how to solve this?

Answer (score 2):

Don't try to serialize a CLOB. Transform it to a String. A CLOB is an object that is connected to the database and allows reading data from it while the connection is open. Serializing it makes no sense, just as serializing a Socket makes no sense.